# TBB tbb::memory_pool<tbb::scalable_allocator<char>> How to use it correctly?

Tags: c++, tbb, memory-pool

I have doubt.

For tbb::memory_pool< tbb::scalable_allocator > shared_memory_pool_;

if that is instantiated in the main thread. And than, I called shared_memory_pool_.malloc(sizeof(my_class)) in a worker thread. Will tbb allocate that size of memory from the main heap, or would it allocate it from the thread "domain" so that the lock contention causes by the normal malloc() would still be avoided?

Comment: Is there a thread-specific heap? Threads typically have their own stack space, but share the heap with process that created them.

Comment: I am unclear with that too, since the document didn't state clearly, but from what i know, scalable_allocator does not allocate memory directly from dynamic heap, so it wouldn't block by the melloc() system call

Comment: I should not say dynamic heap, there is no such thing. what i meant was "share heap" which system call malloc() uses.

Answer (score 3):

The `tbb::memory_pool` is based on the same internals as `tbb::scalable_allocator`. So, once the memory pool grabs the memory initially (in your case as you specified, from `tbb::scalable_allocator` as well), it will use the same mechanisms to distribute and reuse it across the threads. I.e. it is scalable and avoids the global lock as much as possible. Though, as the memory is still a common resource, some thread synchronization is unavoidable anyway. Specifically, I'd expect more contention for initial memory requests since the per-thread caches are not warm yet; and also the scalable_allocator tries to keep the balance between scalability and memory consumption thus it'll not go crazy with per-thread caches redistributing the memory among threads which is also kind of thread synchronization (though more scalable than a lock).

As for the [very] initial memory allocation by scalable_allocator, it goes through `mmap` or `VirtualAlloc` for big enough memory chunks and not through malloc.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/12/19/scalable-memory-pools-community-preview-feature) is some useful descriptions about how to implement a memory pool correctly. Please note that according to that:

> In our implementation, we tried to provide more general functionality
> in thread-safe and scalable way. For that purpose, the implementation
> of the memory pools is based on TBB scalable memory allocator and so
> has similar speed and memory consumption properties.

Hope this helps.